# Cascading Combo Boxes with Entity Framework Core 5.0.8 to populate datagridview

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, windows-forms-designer

I'm trying to cascade selections from one CBO to another in a windows forms project (.net Core 5 framework). I have two tables, Products and Suppliers linked by a linking table (ProductSuppliers). I scaffolded the database into my project with Entity Framework Core Scaffold command (so it made all my entity classes) I have two CBO blocks, one populated with Products and one with suppliers.

```
        private void LoadProductsCBO()
        {
            using (DBContext db = new())
            {
                var products = db.Products.ToList();
                cboProducts.DataSource = products;
                cboProducts.DisplayMember = "ProductName";
                cboProducts.ValueMember = "ProductId";
            }
        }

        private void LoadSuppliersCBO()
        {
            using (DBContext db = new())
            {
                var suppliers = db.Suppliers.ToList();
                cboSuppliers.DataSource = suppliers;
                cboSuppliers.DisplayMember = "SupplierName";
                cboSuppliers.ValueMember = "SupplierID";
            }
        }
```

These two tables are related in a table called ProductSupplier. Now I'm not sure how to make the supplier CBO populate it's list based on the selection made in the first (products cbo). So the products lists contains items like "Air" "Hotel" "Tour Guides" and the suppliers CBO should show only suppliers that offer, for example Air when air is selected in the first CBO.

The second half of this riddle, is that based on that selection I want to populate a datagrid view to list that "for this package, these products are being added and provided by this supplier). So it would just need 2 columns, one for Prods one for Suppliers. It sounded simple a few hours ago, and now I'm realizing it's really not.

The motive for listing these in datagridview is so that I can try and recreate this SQL Select statment in my windows form application:

```
SELECT pps.PackageId, P.PkgName, PD.ProdName, S.SupName
FROM Packages_Products_Suppliers PPS
JOIN Packages p ON PPS.PackageId = P.PackageId
JOIN Products_Suppliers PS ON PPS.ProductSupplierId = PS.ProductSupplierId
JOIN Products PD ON PS.ProductId = PD.ProductId
JOIN Suppliers S ON Ps.SupplierId = S.SupplierId
WHERE P.PackageId = 2
```

But, with being able to assign the WHERE packageid portion by passing in a selected packages value.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I dug into the MSDN all last night and I think I found my own answers so far.

1.) Cascading select from one CBO to the next:

Second checkbox load method:

```
        private void LoadSuppliersCBO(string product)
        {

            using (TravelExpertsContext db = new())
            {
                var productSuppliers = db.ProductsSuppliers.Include(s => s.Product).Include(s => s.Supplier)
                    .ToList().OrderBy(s => s.Supplier.SupName).Select(s => new {s.Product.ProdName, s.Supplier.SupName})
                    .Where(s => s.ProdName == product).ToList().Select(s => s.SupName).ToList();
                var suppliers = db.Suppliers.ToList();
                cboSuppliers.DataSource = productSuppliers;
                cboSuppliers.DisplayMember = "SUpName";
            }
        }
```

1.A) passing the string value of CBO1 selection to set the second CBO list:

```
        private void cboProducts_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (TravelExpertsContext db = new())
            {
                var products = cboProducts.Text;
                LoadSuppliersCBO(products);
            }

        }
```

2.) Then finally drilling down relationships with include/theninclude, then formatting my new list to show the information that I want:

```
        private void LoadPackageContent(int packId)
        {
            using (TravelExpertsContext db = new())
            {
                var content = db.PackagesProductsSuppliers.Include(p => p.ProductSupplier)
                    .ThenInclude(p => p.Supplier).Include(p => p.ProductSupplier)
                    .ThenInclude(p => p.Product).ToList();
                var contentList = content.OrderBy(p => p.PackageId).Select(p =>
                    new {p.PackageId,p.ProductSupplier.Product.ProdName, p.ProductSupplier.Supplier.SupName}).Where(p => p.PackageId == packId).ToList();
                dgvPackageContent.DataSource = contentList;
                dgvPackageContent.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.DisplayedCells;
            }
        }
```

There's probably still a "better" or more correct way to do this, but this is what I came up with.